# Disable video download on VideoJS script

Tags: php, .htaccess, html5-video, video.js

I'm working a script which need to restrict video download for users, they only allow to watch online,

I'm currently use "video.js" script for the player,

I already restricted right click function,

```
jQuery('.video-js').bind('contextmenu',function() { return false; });
```

also added dynamically load videos like

```
https://exmaplle.com/loadvid.php?video=fire.mp4&seskey=1a2asasd125asdasdasdasdas
```

**but when i check using some FireFox extensions. those give ability to download the video file.**

Is there anyway to prevent download videos using browser extensions, or are there have another players which support secure video play.

Answer (score 0):

That jQuery code only disables the browser's context menu. It doesn't stop anyone from downloading the video in any way other than through that menu.

Using token authentication is useful to stop users sharing the link, but won't stop a download extension from downloading the URL from the same session, as the token is still valid.

A segmented format such as HLS or MPEG-DASH is harder for the casual user to download, but there are probably download extensions that will be able to convert them to MP4. DRM ([which Video.js supports](https://github.com/videojs/videojs-contrib-eme)) is the most secure, but obviously comes with a high overhead of cost and complexity.